How to make intersections between road splines at runtime in Unreal Engine 5?
I’m working on a project like the game Cities: Skylines. I’ve been developing a spline-based road system and it successfully creates street curves at runtime. The current problem is how to model complex intersections like in Cities: Skylines.
I think that they didn’t use a static mesh model to make it, because a static mesh is not flexible enough to model the path. How can I do this?


Custom meshes/paths placed over splines.  The logic switches on collision with mesh.
